xTB docking submodule runtime error
I have tried employing the aISS docking submodule of xTB to interact two molecules as suggested here
The calculation finished with "normal termination of xTB;" however, there are several warnings displayed which seem significant.
(1)      Interaction energies
   ---------------------------
 Attention: monomers are not optimized
 Interaction energies are not physical

(2) "[WARNING] Running exception occured
-20- xtb_geoopt: Trying to recover from failed geometry optimization
-19- optimizer_ancopt: Could not relax structure
-18- optimizer_relax: SCF not converged, aborting...
-17- xtb_calculator_singlepoint: Electronic structure method terminated
-16- scf: Self consistent charge iterator did not converge"
-15- xtb_geoopt: Trying to recover from failed geometry optimization
-14- optimizer_ancopt: Could not relax structure
-13- optimizer_relax: SCF not converged, aborting...
-12- xtb_calculator_singlepoint: Electronic structure method terminated
-11- scf: Self consistent charge iterator did not converge"
-10- xtb_geoopt: Trying to recover from failed geometry optimization
-9- optimizer_ancopt: Could not relax structure
-8- optimizer_relax: SCF not converged, aborting...
-7- xtb_calculator_singlepoint: Electronic structure method terminated
-6- scf: Self consistent charge iterator did not converge"
-5- xtb_geoopt: Trying to recover from failed geometry optimization
-4- optimizer_ancopt: Could not relax structure
-3- optimizer_relax: SCF not converged, aborting...
-2- xtb_calculator_singlepoint: Electronic structure method terminated
-1- scf: Self consistent charge iterator did not converge"

(3) and precision error:
  "Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_UNDERFLOW_FLAG IEEE_DENORMAL"

I would appreciate if anyone would enlighten me if these should be resolved and how to resolve them.
Thank you in advance.

Did you test with simple systems before using it with your production systems?

Yes, I tested it on adenine and thymine, which are already individually optimized, and then only errors (1) and (3) occurred. However, the best structure doesn't look anything an interaction between adenine and thymine; it looks like all the atoms exploded and randomly positioned everywhere. I will try to rerun it if it occured again.
